# RegEx for matching a list of chars between two numbers

Tags: regex, regression

When importing to the online store in the description of the goods I need to remove some tags. They are between numbers.

It is necessary exactly the regular expression, because that set of tags, which between the numbers, is already present in the document in many places. And using the replacement search, the document is broken.

How can I remove extra tags, put a dash with it?

Numbers may be different.

#### Attempt

```
[0-9](.*)[0-9]
```

#### Input

```
 13</li></ul></div><div><p>20 kg
```

#### Output:

```
 13-20 kg
```

Comment: If the tags are always the same, why regex? Replace `</li></ul></div><div><p>` with `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/S8rm46/1/) might help you to capture your target output:

```
([0-9]+)([A-Za-z\<\>\/\\]+)([0-9]+)
```

[image]

You can simply call it using <kbd>$2</kbd>, which is the second capturing group and it might capture your desired output.

You may simplify it further if you wish, or add additional boundary, if necessary.

If you wish to filter the HTML, RegEx may not be the best idea to do so. However, if you wish to practice, you might consider using/updating an expression, maybe similar to [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/cqMaZJ/1):

```
([0-9]+)([A-Za-z\<\>\/\\]+)([0-9]+\skg)
```

There are three capturing groups, just to be simple to use, where your desired target is <kbd>\1-\3</kbd> or <kbd>\1-\3</kbd>. You might add other language specific char or escaping, if you may wish so.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be parsing looks like HTML and you should firstly try to avoid parsing HTML using regex. But sometimes when you're dealing with non-nested structures and want to do some quick work, you can use regex. Try this regex,

```
(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

And replace it with `\1-\2`

This will basically start capturing patterns with one or more digit using `(\d+)` and capture it in group1 and then will match one or more non-digits using `\D+` and won't capture them into any groups to exclude them out while replacement and finally again will capture one or more digits using `(\d+)` and capture in group2 and replacing the whole match with `\1-\2` (or `$1-$2` as per your regex flavour) will retain the numbers and will place just hyphen between them.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vUPB4q/1)**

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is finding the first number followed by non-numeric characters and then the second number followed by <kbd>space</kbd> or alpha characters, that's how I would do it:

```
$str = "13</li></ul></div><div><p>20 kg";

echo $res = preg_replace('/^([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+[a-z ]+)$/', '\1-\2', $str);
```

`\1` and `\2` is back-references of the capture groups `()` `([0-9]+)` and `([0-9]+[a-z ]+)`

But, make sure string is exactly same pattern what you posted, because for example `abc 13</li></ul></div><div><p>20 kg` will not work with this pattern.